# I have a corrupt or missing file

Tags: windows, filesystem-corruption

`windows/root>\system32\ntoskrnl.exe`. I don't have the XP CD to repair it, recovery mode
just keeps running, picking up no data.

How do I correct this to be able to try and do
a non-destructive system restore?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an XP CD to fix this.  NTOSKrnl.exe is the system kernel.  It's about as non-trivial a file as you can get.  You may be able to find a Windows XP Recovery Console CD online somewhere (Ultimate Boot CD maybe) and get to a command line and run `chkdsk c: /r` which has about the best chance of working IMX.  If you have a floppy drive, you can use [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310994/en-us) to get to the recovery console.

Otherwise, you will need the XP CD to (at the very minimum) copy the file from the CD ot attempt a repair install of XP.